# Quotes problem text box

Tags: php, html

I have a text box like ,

```
<!--<input type="text"  maxlength="255" name="$key" value="<?php echo $value;?>"  />-->
```

$value is b'bbb"bbb

But it only shows b'bbb as value.Can any1 help ???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Properly escape your data that should be displayed unparsed in HTML using [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/htmlentities):

```
<input type="text"  maxlength="255" name="<?php echo htmlentities($key);?>" value="<?php echo htmlentities($value);?>"  />
```

The quote char (`"`) is breaking your code. It could get more dangerous if you've a `$value` like `"><script>alert("xss")</script>` (it's called XSS and will pop up an alert box with "xss")

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the " in your $value is breaking the html.

Try `echo htmlspecialchars($value);`

Answer (score 0):

you can use htmlentities() to use single and double quotes inside the textbox or when using session values